How to get from_date and to_date of cart_rule and catelog_rule in magento 2?
I'm writing a before plugin   and i need to get from_date  and to_date of cart_rule and catelog_rule in my plugin code

namespace Vendor\CouponBeforePlugin\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem;

class CouponPlugin
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Apply rules to current order item
     *
     * @param AbstractItem $item
     * @param array $rules
     * @param bool $skipValidation
     * @param mixed $couponCode
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     */
    public function beforeApplyRules($item, $rules, $skipValidation, $couponCode)
    {
        $fromdate = $rules->getFromDate();
        $todate = $rules->getToDate();
        var_dump("Working inside plugin");
        var_dump($fromdate);
        var_dump($todate);
        // var_dump($couponCode);
        die;
    }
}```


$rules is array
    public function beforeApplyRules($item, $rules, $skipValidation, $couponCode)
    {
        foreach ($rules as $rule) {
            $fromdate = $rule->getFromDate();
            $todate = $rule->getToDate();
            var_dump("Working inside plugin");
            var_dump($fromdate);
            var_dump($todate);
            // var_dump($couponCode);
        }
        die;
    }

